# Proving $\sec^2\theta\left(1 - \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sin^2A}\right) = 1 - \frac{\tan^2\theta}{\tan^2A}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that: $$\sec^2\theta\left(1 - \dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{\sin^2A}\right) = 1 - \dfrac{\tan^2\theta}{\tan^2A}$$

Please help. I tried changing $\tan$ to $\sin$ from RHS, simplifying LHS but didn’t work ! This is what I tried:

$$RHS = 1-\frac{\frac{sin^2\theta}{cos^2\theta}}{\frac{sin^2A}{cos^2A}}
= \frac{\frac{sin^2A}{cos^2A}-\frac{sin^2\theta}{cos^2\theta}}{\frac{sin^2A}{cos^2A}}
= \frac{sin^2Acos^2\theta-sin^2\theta cos^2A}{cos^2\theta}
= sec^2\theta[sin^2A(1-sin^2\theta)-sin^2\theta(1-sin^2A)]
= sec^2\theta(sin^2A-sin^2\theta)
= ???$$

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to blindly answer homework questions but people will be more willing to help you if you show where and why you are stuck

Comment: Yeah I was editing that when you wrote this comment

Comment: Please show us the exact steps you took to get stuck and we will be able to help you get unstuck

Comment: Hint: Use the [list of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

Comment: Let me call $s=\sin(\theta),c=\cos(\theta),S=\sin(A)$ and $C=\cos(A)$. Then the equation that we want to prove is $\frac{1}{c^2}(1-\frac{s^2}{S^2})=1-\frac{s^2C^2}{S^2c^2}$. Multiplying by $S^2c^2$ we get $S^2-s^2=S^2c^2-s^2C^2$. Remember that $s^2+c^2=1$ and that $S^2+C^2=1$. We can use these to replace $c^2=1-s^2$ and $C^2=1-S^2$ in the wanted equation $S^2-s^2=S^2c^2-s^2C^2$. We get $S^2-s^2=S^2(1-s^2)-s^2(1-S^2)$. You can see now that cancelling the terms that cancel in the right side gives you the left side.

Comment: Thank you very much  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing $\sin^2 A$ from your denominator. Indeed, $$\require{cancel}\dfrac{\frac{\sin^2A}{\cos^2A} - \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}{\frac{\sin^2A}{\cos^2A}} = \dfrac{\frac{\sin^2A\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta\cos^2A}{\cancel{\cos^2A}\cos^2\theta}}{\frac{\sin^2A}{\cancel{\cos^2A}}} = \dfrac{\sin^2A\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta\cos^2A}{\sin^2A\cos^2\theta}$$

And so, in your last line, you have $$\sec^2\theta\left(\dfrac{\sin^2A - \sin^2\theta}{\sin^2A}\right) = \sec^2\theta\left(1 - \dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{\sin^2A}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sec^2 \theta  (1 - \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\sin^2 A})$$
$$= \sec^2 \theta - \frac{\tan^2 \theta}{\sin^2 A}$$
$$= 1 + \tan^2 \theta - \frac{\tan^2 \theta}{\sin^2 A}$$
$$= 1 + \tan^2 \theta (1 - \frac{1}{\sin^2 A})$$
$$= 1 - \tan^2 \theta \cot^2 A$$
$$= 1 - \frac{\tan^2 \theta}{\tan^2 A}$$

Comment: FYI - when typesetting trig function use `\sin`, `\cos`, etc. This makes the posting more readable. For example $sin^2 A$ vs. $\sin^2 A$.

Comment: Thanks:D. I've edited my post